# month level fixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, meta-analysis, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to understand the effect of migration of a male member on the employment outcomes of left-behind women. I have monthly observations for 5 years. I am using a fixed effects model with month level and year level fixed effects. The employment outcome is the number of hours spent on family farm by women. I reason I am using month-level fixed effects is because I think that there might be seasonal shocks in the agriculture sector. These seasonal shocks may affect my dependent variable as well as the explanatory variable.
therefore, i want to control for the month-level effects. Is my logic for using month level fixed effects correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic for including month in the model seems sound. You can use monthly indicators as so-called fixed (non-varying) or random (varying) effects. One reason you might consider them as varying effects is that you say the following:

> These seasonal shocks may affect my dependent variable as well as the
> explanatory variable.

This suggests that the effect of your explanatory variable depends on the month. If month is treated as non-varying (fixed), then this would entail an interaction between the month factor and the explanatory variable. If month is treated as varying (random), then you would allow the slope for the explanatory variable to vary by month. I don't know what software you are using, but I'll assume it is R and `lme4`.

The non-varying (fixed) effect month model would be something like this:

```
fe <- lmer(employment ~ 1 + key_pred*as.factor(month) + as.factor(year) + (1|id), d = data)
```

The varying (random) effect month model would instead be the following:

```
re <- lmer(employment ~ 1 + key_pred + as.factor(year) + (key_pred|month) + (1|id), d = data)
```

Which of these should you prefer? The answer often depends on your field. If you are in economics, then probably the non-varying (fixed) effect model is more common. You may treat persons as fixed in economics as well. I assumed you were using a mixed model given you tagged it, so apologies if I am mistaken.

In some other fields, the second model is often seen. The advantage of it is that you get estimates of variability in the form of variances/standard deviations in both month intercepts and the key predictor effect. On the intercept side, this tells you about between-month variability in employment. The slope variance is an estimate of effect heterogeneity across months on employment. You can use it to construct 95% [prediction intervals](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html) for the explanatory variable effect on employment.